# Как поровну разделить экран Android в TableLayout. Android

Tags: android, вёрстка, разметка

Как разбить сделать, чтобы два TableROW поровну делили экран и заполняли экран на 100% в ширину?

Есть код:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textTask"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DateLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textTask"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/datetimebackground"
            android:text="Cегодня"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textTask"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textTask"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textTask"
            android:layout_marginEnd="62dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/datetimebackground"
            android:text="Без времени"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: пробовали использовать `weidht="0.5"` может и без `TableRow` обойтись

Comment: Как можно делить TableRow по ширине? и зачем вообще это делать? Это же строковый класс, строчка в TableLayout. Он работает по типу таблицы, если вы разместите два значения, в одной строке(TableRow), то у Вас и будет разделения на две одинаковые колонки. Сейчас попробую пример в ответ накидать.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:background="#abb3b2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableRow
    android:background="#39743e"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Дата"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Время"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Сегодня"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Текущее время"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="08.11.2015"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="09.11.2015"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20:50"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</TableRow>
```